# Function within the if condition

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, comparison

I'm using this function right now:

```
function() {
   if (function1() == function2()){
       // Do something.
     };
 };
```

So each time I call the `function()`, the `function1()` and `function2()` will also run. 
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Remove it from the code? (If this is not the correct answer you should think about clarifying your question ...)

Comment: Why would you want them not to run? What are you trying to achieve with the comparison?

Answer (score 4):

It's not altogether clear what you mean here, but if the outputs of `function1` and `function2` are invariant, then you could declare the outcome of your conditional outside of the scope of your function:

```
var isConditionMet = function1() == function2();
function someFunc(){
   if (isConditionMet){
       //Do something.
   };
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So function1() == function2() is not within the function someFun() any more.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but what's with the extra semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function and then expect it not to be called. This is some paradox.

Ok! But here is a dirty solution.

```
var callJustOnce = 1;

function (){
   if(callJustOnce) {
     callJustONce -= 1;
     if (function1()== function2()){
       //Do something.
     }
   }
 }
```